# 0-1 Knapsack revisited

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, knapsack-problem

Well, this is an old 0-1 Knapsack problem but after finding the total maximum price I can get I need to find the the items I can carry. But for the following test case ( total 3 items)

```
10 (max weight that I can carry)
5 3 (weight and value for each item)
5 2
6 5
```

Here maximum price is 5. But for weight it can be `6` or `10(5+5)` . Both will give the same price but obviously the feasible would be to take 6 kg item than 10 kg. I want hint how can I calculate this from the dp matrix. I got the following matrix for this test case.

```
0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 
0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 5 
0 0 0 0 3 5 5 5 5 5
```

Using this algo it finds weight as 10 but the optimal is 6 kg.

```
i=n, k=W(max weight)// n= total items

while i,k > 0

if dp[i,k] ≠ dp[i−1,k] then 
mark the ith item as in the knapsack
i = i−1, k = k-w(weight of ith item)

else
i = i−1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to iteratively run the knapsack algorithm on varying bag sizes, and chose the smallest bag that still gives you the same value the original bag gave you.

This can be done using [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on the weigths `[0,W]` - so you will run the knapsack algorithm total of `O(logW)` times, giving you total of `O(nW*log(W))` solution that finds maximal value and minimal possible bag size.

**Idea of how to imply the binary search:**

Let the original bag be of size `W`, run `knapsack(W,items)`, and get the `value`. Now check if `knapsack(W/2,items)` still returns `value`. If it does - search in range `(0,W/2]`. If it doesn't, search in range `(W/2,W]`, until you find the smallest bag size that returns `value`.

Comment: can you please explain the scenario where we can apply binary search on weights

Comment: @Imposter: let the original bag be of size `W`, run `knapsack(W,items)`, and get the `value`. Now check if `knapsack(W/2,items)` still returns value. if it does - search in range (0,W/2]. If it doesn't, search in range (W/2,W], until you find the smallest bag size that returns `value`. Is it clear? If it is - I will add it to the answer.

Comment: I do not understand the follow up question

Comment: In pruning concept we eliminate the extra computation which cant lead to a optimised solution . so in the same way we run knapsack(W,items), and get the value. Now check if knapsack(W/2,items) still returns value. if it does - search in range (0,W/2]. If it doesn't, search in range (W/2,W], until you find the smallest bag size that returns value. In the above process we are eliminating the either of the two half.. I hope i'm clear

Comment: @Imposter: Exactly, each iteration is cutting half of the range, so to get a range containing a single element - you need `O(logW)` iterations, each costing `O(nW)` (because each iteration invokes the knapsack algorithm)

Comment: Used this technique but not working on a similar spoj problem.. TLE